# Accessing environment variables that don't map to valid shell variable names

Tags: bash

I'm trying to figure out how to sanely and portably (as much as possible) deal with environment variables with names that don't map to valid shell variables. It is critical that results be byte-for-byte accurate, so I'm unwilling to go through hacks such as parsing the output of the `env` tool.

```
env 'Invalid Name=Some Value' bash <<'EOF'
s='Invalid Name'
printf '%q\n' "${!s}"
EOF
```

I would hope that the above code would emit `Some Value`; instead, however, it returns an empty string.

Comment: I don't understand the question : how can a defined environment variable have an non-valid name ? ... I'm confused ^^

Comment: Environments are a construct of an operating system, not any particular shell. Shells merely provide one mechanism for exporting its variables to the environment, and it's possible that one shell's notion of a valid variable name differs from another's, with neither encompassing all valid environment variable names. For example, see the definition in the POSIX spec (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html), which states that environment variables that don't contain valid characters must be tolerated, if not accepted.

Comment: Or for a simpler example, simply run `env "foo bar=3" env | grep foo`

Comment: @OlivierDulac Note the example, which uses the `env` tool to create just such a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One unportable approach (Linux-only) is to parse `/proc/self/environ`:

```
declare -A environ
while IFS='' read -r -d ''; do
  var=${REPLY%%=*}
  val=${REPLY#*=}
  environ[$var]="$val"
done </proc/self/environ
printf '%q\n' "${environ["Invalid Name"]}"
```

Comment: +1 You can read from the `env` command instead of `/proc/self/environ` to make this more portable.

Comment: @chepner Is the `env` command's output deterministic in terms of its quoting, non-ASCII characters, etc?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. I suspect it is dependent on the locale in effect.